# JUnit compilation and execution error

Tags: java, maven, junit

The app directories/packages structure is the next one:

```
scr/main/java
-mockitoinit.controller
-mockitoinit.model
-mockitoinit.repository
-mockitoinit.service
-- AppInterface.java
-- AppIntefacaImpl.java

scr/test/java
-mockitoinit.service
--AppInterfaceImplTest.java
```

The AppInterfaceImplTest.java code is that follows:

```
package mockitoinit.service;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;

public class AppInterfaceImplTest {

    private AppInterface app;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
    }

    @Test
    public final void test() {
        assert(true);
    }
}
```

So, when I execute mnv compiler:testCompile it fails. The log is that follows:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Init Mocks 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ mockitoinit ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\arturo\eclipse_tmp\mockitoinit\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-cli) @ mockitoinit ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!

[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\arturo\eclipse_tmp\mockitoinit\target\test-classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /C:/Users/arturo/eclipse_tmp/mockitoinit/src/test/java/mockitoinit/service/AppInterfaceImplTest.java:[11,17] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class AppInterface
  location: class mockitoinit.service.AppInterfaceImplTest
[INFO] 1 error
```

Because cannot find source code classes in src/main/java directory.

Thanks in advance,
A. Seixo

Comment: Import AppInterface

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, your `AppInterface` package is `mockitoinit.service`. It means that you have to write `import mockitoinit.service.AppInterface` in your `AppInterfaceImplTest`.

UPD:
As you showed example in comments - it is better to use the same packages for test and source code. For example if you have package for sources `org.kappa.hibernate.job` tests for classes from this page better to store in the same package `org.kappa.hibernate.job` but in `test` directory

Comment: Also I personally recommend to use IDE, such as IntelliJ IDEA or Eclipse. This IDEs can help you to recognize and recommend to add imports and explain some of compilation errors.

Comment: I do that you said from the beggining but the problem persists. Sometimes java finds the package for the class to test, but in many cases loose the link and and the error appears again in the import clause in the test class (so I have to rebuild pom and try to compile tests again). It's the first time I have this problem and it`s very hard to fix.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse Photon

Comment: Could you share a link to your project?

Comment: The project is differente but with the same problem as above.

Comment: Just move your tests from `hibernateapp` package to `org.kappa.hibernate.job..` package

Comment: I did that you tell me before and I receive the same error in the console.

Comment: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-cli) on project hibernateapp: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /C:/Users/arturo/eclipse_tmp/hibernateapp/src/test/java/org/kappa/hibernate/job/StudentDaoTest.java:[6,37] package org.kappa.hibernate.job.utils does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/arturo/eclipse_tmp/hibernateapp/src/test/java/org/kappa/hibernate/job/StudentDaoTest.java:[12,9] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class AppUtils
[ERROR] location: class org.kappa.hibernate.job.StudentDaoTest
[ERROR] -> [Help 1

Comment: I get this error message when I try to set up maven: An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Folder cannot be cast to org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject

Comment: The test execution problem appears only when I use a project created with spring initializr. When I use Eclipse, just New->Spring Started Project all works properly, so I think the problem is in any Maven set up item.